# jQuery with Input Type = "Number"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple question, but I am looking for the right way to handle this.

I've broken it down to the most simplistic example that still shows the problem.

Let's say I have a basic HTML table:

```
<table id="customerTable">
    <caption class="bg-primary h4">Customer Overview</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer ID</th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th># Projects</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Enterprise Management</td>
            <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            etc ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then I have a input type:

```
<input id="colorColumnRed" type="number" />
```

The jQuery is as follows, with `redText` being basic CSS to change the color to red.  I'm handling both the `change` and `keyup` events to try to capture two situations.

```
$(function () {

   $('#colorColumnRed').bind('change keyup', function () {
        var colId = $('#colorColumnRed').val();
        $('#customerTable td:nth-child(' + colId + ')').toggleClass('redText');
    });

});
```

The problem is, when they user **types** a number into the numeric field it works as expected.  However, if they then change focus to another input, the CSS **reverts**.

If they use the numeric **up/down selector** instead, the change *persists* after the control loses focus.

What am I missing with the jQuery selector to stop it from reverting when manually entered on losing focus?  I've tried the various `focus` events, `blur`, etc and can't find one that changes this behavior.

Comment: How about `$('#colorColumnRed').bind('input'` ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/8euy18np/

Comment: Could you perhaps upload a plunkr or so?

Comment: If only me not understanding the exact problem.

Comment: @RayonDabre That was the one, thanks.

Comment: @Patrick, Glad to help you mate!

Answer (score 1):

@Rayon Dabre was quick to answer with the easy, quick fix.

```
$('#colorColumnRed').bind('input')
```